# How to add gm_authFailure in the following code?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to work on google maps api and i am having some trouble in using the gm_authFailure() function in my working code.

I have tried to put the function in the following code but it always give some errors while compiling.

```
export default class Map extends Component {

render(){

      return(

        <MyMapComponent
         {...this.props}

        googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC_ECg0ZGIReSnKf5Ax-Bj0Q3DLXuxvajI" //google maps api key
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}

        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%`, width: `75%` }} />}  //map properties

        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
      )
  }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What are those "some errors while compiling" you get?

Comment: @Gonzo345 the compiler isnt accepting the the function inside the above lines of code

Comment: @Gonzo345 further it is failing to compile and the following error is displaying:  Parsing error: Unexpected token